# Using an array formula in countifs range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Afternoon guys,

I'm trying to evaluate a countifs formula using an array as the criteria range.

My table is named tblSkillsMatrix and is set up with the following headers;
Role    Staff   Skill 1 Skill 2 Skill 3 Skill 4 Skill 5 Skill 6 Skill 7 Skill 8 Skill 9 Skill 10 etc

There is a corresponding table called tblRoles.  The headers are Role titles and the rows hold the required skill e.g. Skill 1, Skill3, Skill 5, Skill 8 etc

I want my countifs function to count the number of items that show as trained under the relevant skill for the corresponding Role.  The normal formula looks something like this;

```
=COUNTIFS(tblSkillsMatrix[[#All],[Role]],'Skills Summary'!C16,tblSkillsMatrix[[#All],[Skill 1]],"Trained",tblSkillsMatrix[[#All],[Skill 3]],"Trained",tblSkillsMatrix[[#All],[Skill 5]],"Trained",tblSkillsMatrix[[#All],[Skill 8]],"Trained")
```

Is there anyway to use an array formula to work out which columns I should use?  So the formula would look like this instead;

```
=COUNTIFS(tblSkillsMatrix[[#All],[Role]],'Skills Summary'!C16,Array{columns to evaluate},"Trained")
```

Many thanks

Comment: Of what should the part {columns to evaluate} part of Array{columns to evaluate} consist? The full table column references (tblSkillsMatrix[[#All],[Skill 1], etc.)? If so, this won't really make the formula any more concise. Perhaps you wish to reference the desired columns via their relative position within the table (e.g. {1,4,6})?

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping.  In tblSkillsMatrix, the column headers are Skill 1, Skill 2 etc.  In tblRoles, the column headers are the names of job types and the rows show which Skills they should have e.g. Skill 1, Skill 5 etc.  Using an array formula {=INDIRECT("tblRoles[JobType]")} returns all the skills listed under column heading "JobType".  So this may be Skill 3, Skill 8 etc.  I need to be able to tell the countifs formula to use those columns in tblSkillsMatrix.  Hope this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Array formula****:

`=SUM(IF(tblSkillsMatrix[Role]='Skills Summary'!C16,IF(MMULT(0+(T(OFFSET(INDIRECT("tblSkillsMatrix["&TRANSPOSE(tblRoles[JobType])&"]"),ROW(tblSkillsMatrix[Role])-MIN(ROW(tblSkillsMatrix[Role])),))="Trained"),ROW(tblRoles[JobType])^0)=COUNTA(tblRoles[JobType]),1)))`

Note that I changed your table references to exclude the headers, since I presume that you don't actually need to include them in the count?

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks, but I don't think I've asked quite the right question!!! My bad... What I need is to count the rows where the JobType & ALL Skills on that row for a team member are shown as trained.  Sorry, its been a really long day!

Comment: ok - I've got this to work so far  {=SUM((tblSkillsMatrix[Role]="Civil")*(tblSkillsMatrix[Skill 3]="Trained")*(tblSkillsMatrix[Skill 1]="Trained")*(tblSkillsMatrix[Skill 5]="Trained")*(tblSkillsMatrix[Skill 8]="Trained"))}  But how can I change it to something like this {=SUM((tblSkillsMatrix[Role]="Civil")*INDIRECT("tblSkillsMatrix["&tblRoles[Civil]&"]"="Trained"))}?

Comment: Ah, ok. I'm afraid that that makes the required solution quite complex. Have amended the post.

Comment: I really appreciate your help with this, I'm fairly new to array formulas, I'd normally be doing this in vb!  Did you say you amended the post? I can't see it...

Comment: Well - the new updated formula is about three times longer, so I'm surprised to hear you say that you can't see it!

Comment: It showed up on the app on my phone but not on my PC browser for some reason!  I'll take a look at it now.  I really appreciate all your time on this

Comment: That worked a treat!  I can't thank you enough.  I'll probably spend another day trying to work it out, but you've done me a huge, huge favour!!!